# Insert javascript in head from template with magento extension

Tags: javascript, php, xml, magento, templates

I am trying to insert some js code in all/some pages of my website through my extension.

I need a dynamic version (hosted in a .phtml file) of this (the script part):

```
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/text" name="simple_example_javascript_block"> 
                <action method="setText">
                    <text><![CDATA[
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("foo");
                    </script>
                    //]]></text>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

I cannot find any working code on SO or on Google...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you with use of CDATA

```
<reference name="head">
<block type="core/text" name="your.block.name">
    <action method="setText">
        <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>]]></text>
    </action>
</block>
</reference>
```

**Edited** : To insert JS code to some pages via your extension, all you need to do is from your extension layout file, by referencing pages you can add js file like below

```
<cms_index_index> <!--/ To add js only in homepage similarly for other pages take their layout handle -->
   <reference name="head">
      <!--/ to add from root ie. js/yourmodulename/script.js -->
      <action method="addJs"><script>yourmodulename/script.js</script></action> 
      <!--/ to add from skin activated theme / base ie. skin/frontend/base/default/js/yourmodulename/script.js -->
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/yourmodulename/script.js</name></action>
   </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: Thanks but i dont want to use CDATA but a separate template

Comment: @Sucrenoir you can upvote/accept the answer, if not provide me feedback.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i needed a dynamic js.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used :

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="checkout.success.js">
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="luckycycle_js" as="luckycycle_js" template="Luckycycle/js.phtml" output="toHtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

And Luckycycle/js.phtml is dynamic and generated by php.